# Reading csv from S3 and inserting into a MySQL table with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to automate the loading of a csv into a MySQL table when it's received into a S3 bucket.

My strategy is that S3 launches an event when it receives a file into a specified bucket (let's call it 'bucket-file'). This is event is notified to an AWS Lambda function that will download and process the file inserting each row into a MySql table (let's call it 'target_table').

We have to take into consideration that RDS is in a VPC.

The current permission configuration of the bucket is:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-file/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've created a role with the following policies, AmazonS3FullAccess and AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole attached to the AWS Lambda function.

The lambda code is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import logging
import os
import sys
import uuid
import pymysql
import csv
import rds_config


rds_host  = rds_config.rds_host
name = rds_config.db_username
password = rds_config.db_password
db_name = rds_config.db_name


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS mysql instance succeeded")

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def handler(event, context):

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'] 
    download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)

    s3_client.download_file(bucket, key,download_path)

    csv_data = csv.reader(file( download_path))

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        for idx, row in enumerate(csv_data):

            logger.info(row)
            try:
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO target_table(column1, column2, column3)' \
                                'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")'
                                , row)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(e)

            if idx % 100 == 0:
                conn.commit()

        conn.commit()

    return 'File loaded into RDS:' + str(download_path)
```

I've been testing the function and S3 sends the event when a file is uploaded, Lambda connects to the RDS instance and get the notification. I've checked that the bucket name is 'bucket-file' and the filename is also right. The problem is when the function reaches the line `s3_client.download_file(bucket, key,download_path)` where it gets stuck until the lamdba expiration time is reached.

Watching the logs it says:

```
[INFO]  2017-01-24T14:36:52.102Z    SUCCESS: Connection to RDS mysql instance succeeded
[INFO]  2017-01-24T14:36:53.282Z    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): bucket-files.s3.amazonaws.com
[INFO]  2017-01-24T14:37:23.223Z    Starting new HTTPS connection (2): bucket-files.s3.amazonaws.com
2017-01-24T14:37:48.684Z Task timed out after 60.00 seconds
```

I've also read that if you are working within a VPC, in order to access S3 bucket you have to create a VPC Endpoint that grants access to S3 for this subnet. I've also tried this solution but the result is the same.

I'd appreciate some ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it!

The problem was the VPC issue. As I said, I created an VPC Endpoint to make S3 service accessible form my VPC, but I had my route table wrongly configured.

So, in conclusion, if you are working in a VPC with lambda and you want to access to S3, you need to create a VPC Endpoint. Besides, if you want to access any other internet service outside your VPC, you need to configure a NAT Gateway.